# SSIS output error when there are no records on Data Flow Task

Tags: ssis, db2, dataflowtask

I'm querying records from an IBM DB2 database. If there are records, the data flow task runs fine, when there are no records I get this error:

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source CENTRAL (ExtraLog) returned error
>   code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the
>   pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code
>   is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.
>
> [ODBC Source CENTRAL (ExtraLog) [2]] Error: Open Database Connectivity
>   (ODBC) error occurred. state: '07005'. Native Error Code: -501.
>   [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0501 - Cursor
>   SQL_CUR0A4463B0 not open.

Again, it only happens when I have no records. Any ideas on how to stop this error? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be an issue with SSIS, the `SQL0501 - Cursor SQL_CUR0A4463B0 not open` error suggests some problem with DB2

Comment: @Russtopher The SQL0501 is normally an application error (not a Db2 error). This error happens when the application EITHER tries to close a cursor that is not open, or the application tries to fetch from a cursor that is not open. CHECK your *versions* of software components and ensure they are *latest*.

Comment: I’m not familiar with what a cursor is or what it’s for. It’s just a select statement I’m using. And it only throws the error when it returns no records.